# javascript copy text utf16 with font info to clipboard

Tags: javascript, browser, clipboard, rtf

This is the demo website:
http://symbolsearch.org/

Summany the website:

> List all symbols (with tags) supported by a font, help user
>   quick-lookup a symbol.

I'm stucking in **copy the symbol** (an utf-16 character) **to a rich text editor** (like MS Word).
Some symbol can be copy to Word directly (my system has already installed the font), but some are not (display as another symbol).
e.g. I **copy** `asterisk`, `plus` or `question` to **MS Word** and **display as another character**, but if I copy `bomb`, `futbol` or `git` to **MS Word**, it display as expected.
If I copy the symbol to a raw-text editor (like notepad), and copy that into Word, 100% display as expected!

```
function copyText(id) {
    // clipboard is an object, helping me to write data to clipboard
    var dt = new clipboard.DT();

    // element id='just_symbol' is contain only the symbol string
    dt.setData("text/plain", $('#just_symbol').html());
    // this data contain font info, the font is installed in the system
    dt.setData("text/html", '<font face="@fontCurrent.FontName">' + $('#just_symbol').html() +'</font>');
    clipboard.write(dt);
}
```

I'm using a clipboard inspector, when I copy the same data form Character Map (of Windows), the clipboard inspector show '**Rich Text Format**' field, can paste data to Word perfectly. Can I copy data (by javascript) into that field?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery, which apparently cannot convert emoji/Unicode symbols to HTML entities. `$('#just_symbol').html()` leaves the symbol encoded in Unicode.

Since other web APIs like [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) don't seem to handle this either, I suggest using something like https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he :

```
var symbol = $("#just_symbol").text();
var dt = new clipboard.DT();
dt.setData("text/plain", symbol);
dt.setData("text/html", he.encode(symbol));
clipboard.write(dt);
```

### Regarding RTF

Some applications may automatically convert pasted HTML to RTF (to the best of their ability), but browsers currently only support `text/plain` and `text/html`.

The new Clipboard API spec will add more data types, but [`application/rtf` is currently not currently planned](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#writing-to-clipboard). You can request consideration for RTF in the draft spec repo: https://github.com/w3c/clipboard-apis

Comment: Thank you. I realize that any character from F000 to F099, when copied with format (in text/html) will be changed to a different character after pasted to Word. (I dont know about E000-EFFF because it have not contained in my example font), but the character from F100+ will be exactly the same.

Comment: But the character from **F100+**  even **10000+** will be exactly the same.

 If I copy as `text/plain`, after pasted to Word, I manually change the character's format then the character (symbol) I want is shown.

Do you know why this happened? (The characters from **F000** to **F099** are not shown as expected after pasted to Word, they display as different characters)

Comment: _one more question_:  flags are always contained in pair, such as . My font have a glyph that represent , but when I copy from the website, and pasted to Word, it show as `N` and `Z`, not the flag. Are there a way to handle this?

Comment: Copying the HTML generated using https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he works for me on macOS. If the problem is specific to Word on Windows, it's not as easy for me to test. :-(