# Copy emoji to clipboard in Svelte

Tags: svelte, clipboard, emoji

In my app I want to copy an emoji to the clipboard. The [*navigator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) interface stores and returns the Unicode value and not the emoji. I am assuming that I need to encode the emoji value and have attempted to use the [*he* package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473532/javascript-copy-text-utf16-with-font-info-to-clipboard)

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(he.encode(emojis[key]));
```

To do that, I understand that I need to install [*json plugin*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568186/importing-a-js-npm-library-in-svelte)

I have the following:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.0",
    "rollup": "^3.15.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^4.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.55.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        json(),
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                dev: !production
            }
        }),

        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte'],
            exportConditions: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),

        !production && serve(),


        !production && livereload('public'),


        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="../node_modules/he/he.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

The error I get is

```
p://localhost:8080/node_modules/he/he.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: You should just `import "he"` in the top level script tag. Side note, if you wanna insert anything into `<head>` tag as verbatim, you should use `<svelte:head>` tag.